# Get count of all database rows with specific UserID and display on cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing a website with user profile pages, these profiles are for creators. On each creator page, is the ability to "Favorite" the account. When a website user favorites a creator page, I store the ID of the creator and the ID of the user that liked the page in single row in my database.

On my home page, I want to display the total amount of "Favorites" a creator page has and I figured I need to do that by summing all rows that contain a specific creator ID to a list and `Count`-ing that in Razor. As of right now, I have the creator accounts displaying on my home page but I am not sure how I can obtain the creatorID in my controller so that I can use that to find all rows in the database with `getAllFavoritesByCreatorID(string creatorID)`. Here is my code:

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new HomeViewModel();
    model.FeaturedAlbum = EntityDataAccess.GetCurrentFeaturedAlbum();
    if(model.FeaturedAlbum == null)
    {
        model.FeaturedAlbum = new FeaturedAlbum();
        model.FeaturedAlbum.Album = new Album();
        model.FeaturedAlbum.Album.AccountInfo = new AccountInfo();
    }
    //here's where relevant code starts
    model.InspiredCreator = EntityDataAccess.GetAllCreatorAccountInfo();
    model.Favorite = EntityDataAccess.GetAllFavoritesByCreatorID(need a input arg here);
    model.TrendingSongs = EntityDataAccess.GetTopPlayedSongsByCount(51).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

Home model:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public FeaturedAlbum FeaturedAlbum { get; set; }
    public List<Song> TrendingSongs { get; set; }
    //The AccountInfo class contains the creator UserID
    public List<AccountInfo> InspiredCreator { get; set; }
    //the Favorite class contains the creatorID and the userID of the user that favorited the page
    public List<Favorite> Favorite { get; set; }
}
```

EntityDataAccess.cs, this is how I am trying to find all rows in db with specific CreatorID:

```
public static List<Favorite> GetAllFavoritesByCreatorID(string creatorID)
{
    using (var Context = GetContext())
    {
        return Context.Favorites.Where(x => x.CreatorID == creatorID).ToList();
    }
}
public static List<AccountInfo> GetAllCreatorAccountInfo()
{
    using (var Context = GetContext())
    {
        return Context.AccountInfoes.Where(x => x.CreatorFL == true).OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2).ToList();
    }
}
```

Here's my Home page cshtml where I display the the creator accounts:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.InspiredCreator)
{
    //the following item.UserID is the creator ID I need on controller side
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Creator", new { ID = item.UserID })">
    <div class="feat-creators-indi">
        <div class="creator-img-container">
            <img class="creator-img" src="@(item.ImageURL != null ? (item.ImageURL) + "-/format/jpeg/-/quality/lightest/" : "https://unearthapp.io/resources/images/artist_ph.jpg")" alt="@item.DisplayName Creator" />
        </div>
        <div class="creator-bio-container">
            <div class="creator-txt-center">
                <div class="creator-name">@item.DisplayName</div>
                <div class="creator-bio">@item.Bio</div>
                <div class="creator-followers">//NEED TO INSERT FOLLOWER COUNT HERE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
}
```

How can I get the total number of rows in my Favorites db that contain a specific creatorID?

**EDIT** I'm adding my `AccountInfo.cs` and `Favorite.cs` to help explain:

```
public partial class AccountInfo
{

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public AccountInfo()
    {
        this.Albums = new HashSet<Album>();
        this.DownloadHistories = new HashSet<DownloadHistory>();
        this.Spotlights = new HashSet<Spotlight>();
        this.Videos = new HashSet<Video>();
    }


    public int AccountInfoID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public string FacebookURL { get; set; }
    public string TwitterURL { get; set; }
    public string InstagramURL { get; set; }
    public string SpotifyURL { get; set; }
    public string iTunesURL { get; set; }
    public string YouTubeURL { get; set; }
    public string WebURL { get; set; }
    public string MerchURL { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> AllowCollaborationFL { get; set; }
    public bool VerifiedFL { get; set; }
    public bool NeedsVerificationFL { get; set; }
    public bool AdminFL { get; set; }
    public bool LabelFL { get; set; }
    public bool CreatorFL { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<DownloadHistory> DownloadHistories { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Spotlight> Spotlights { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }

    }

}
```

and the other class:

```
public partial class Favorite
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    //ID of user that liked the page
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    //creatorID of the page the user liked
    public string CreatorID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Liked { get; set; }

}
```

**Edit 2** Here's my current Debug output when on the home page, the same UserID is used:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get `UserID` of accounts in the controller action.

```
model.InspiredCreator = EntityDataAccess.GetAllCreatorAccountInfo();
model.FavoriteCounts = new List<AccountInfoFavoriteCount>();
foreach (var creator in model.InspiredCreator)
{
    var favoriteCount = new AccountInfoFavoriteCount()
    {
        CreatorID = creator.UserID
    };
    favoriteCount.FavoriteCount = EntityDataAccess.GetAllFavoritesByCreatorID(creator.UserID);
    model.FavoriteCounts.Add(favoriteCount);
}
```

Also, you want to get `Count` instead of entire list of `Favorite` records. So, modify the EF method;

```
public static int GetAllFavoritesByCreatorID(string creatorID)
{
    using (var Context = GetContext())
    {
        return Context.Favorites.Where(x => x.CreatorID == creatorID).Count();
    }
}
```

Then change the model;

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public FeaturedAlbum FeaturedAlbum { get; set; }
    public List<Song> TrendingSongs { get; set; }
    public List<AccountInfo> InspiredCreator { get; set; }
    public List<AccountInfoFavoriteCount> FavoriteCounts { get; set; } //Change this line
}

public class AccountInfoFavoriteCount
{
    public int FavoriteCount { get; set; }

    public string CreatorID { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, in the view you can get the counts like `Model.FavoriteCounts`.

Comment: I think we're on the right track. My creatorId is a string, so I initialized as `creatorId = ""` how can I integrate this into my cshtml now?

Comment: getting closer, I think that since we are using FirstOrDefault it is pulling the same userID on our controller. I added two debug lines beneath `creatorId = item.UserID` to print out the `creatorID`. There are two Creator accounts that are displayed on the home page and the creatorID you see in the console twice is the first account. I edited my original post with an image

Comment: So, do you want to display favourite count of two different account ?

Comment: that's correct, here's an image of the home page. Basically whatever the "favorite" count of the first creator (the one on the left) is reflected on the second account. When I Debug output the follower count it prints out the two correct counts https://snag.gy/muIYrU.jpg

Comment: Well, I updated the answer. This case changes a bit our logic.

Comment: sorry if I made it confusing. Receiving error on this line:
`model.FavoriteCounts = new List<AccountInfoFavoriteCount>();`

Error states: the type of namespace 'List<>' could not be found. Do I need to create a brand new class for `AccountInfoFavoriteCount`? I simply kept it in the Model as you did

Comment: "using System.Collections.Generic" add the namespace.

Comment: ah yep, forgot to add that namespace to the controller, good catch. This is what I see on my home page now though: https://snag.gy/Y6mcyU.jpg

Comment: Iterate the Model.FavoriteCounts list or get single item like "Model.FavoriteCounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CreatorID == "xxx");" and display it.

Comment: by iterate do you mean to do something like Model.FavoriteCounts[x] where I use a counter to increment x in my cshtml code? Out of curiosity I tried to just hard code `Model.FavoriteCounts[0] and didn't receive the first count value. So sorry this is taking so long and I really appreciate your help @Rainman

Comment: "Model.FavoriteCounts[0].FavoriteCount" try this.

Comment: phew, that worked thank you so much for your help :)